# Purge old release from Nexus 3

Tags: nexus, nexus3

I use Nexus 3 and I want to delete my old releases. In Nexus 2 there is a scheduled task called `Remove Releases From Repository`. It seems that this tasks is missing in Nexus 3.

How can we delete old release from Nexus 3 ?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-10821 if you want to follow along.

Answer (score 13):

Since the release of nexus 3 you can deploy groovy scripts to the nexus manager. Simply create a new execute script task and use the following script:

```
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.StorageFacet;
import org.sonatype.nexus.common.app.GlobalComponentLookupHelper
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.maintenance.MaintenanceService
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.ComponentMaintenance
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.Query;
import org.sonatype.nexus.script.plugin.RepositoryApi
import org.sonatype.nexus.script.plugin.internal.provisioning.RepositoryApiImpl
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.slf4j.Logger

// ----------------------------------------------------
// delete these rows when this script is added to nexus
RepositoryApiImpl repository = null;
Logger log = null;
GlobalComponentLookupHelper container = null;
// ----------------------------------------------------

def retentionDays = 30;
def retentionCount = 10;
def repositoryName = 'maven-releases';
def whitelist = ["org.javaee7.sample/javaee7-simple-sample", "org.javaee7.next/javaee7-another-sample"].toArray();


log.info(":::Cleanup script started!");
MaintenanceService service = container.lookup("org.sonatype.nexus.repository.maintenance.MaintenanceService");
def repo = repository.repositoryManager.get(repositoryName);
def tx = repo.facet(StorageFacet.class).txSupplier().get();
def components = null;
try {
    tx.begin();
    components = tx.browseComponents(tx.findBucket(repo));
}catch(Exception e){
    log.info("Error: "+e);
}finally{
    if(tx!=null)
        tx.close();
}

if(components != null) {
    def retentionDate = DateTime.now().minusDays(retentionDays).dayOfMonth().roundFloorCopy();
    int deletedComponentCount = 0;
    int compCount = 0;
    def listOfComponents = ImmutableList.copyOf(components);
    def previousComp = listOfComponents.head().group() + listOfComponents.head().name();
    listOfComponents.reverseEach{comp ->
        log.info("Processing Component - group: ${comp.group()}, ${comp.name()}, version: ${comp.version()}");
        if(!whitelist.contains(comp.group()+"/"+comp.name())){
            log.info("previous: ${previousComp}");
            if(previousComp.equals(comp.group() + comp.name())) {
                compCount++;
                log.info("ComCount: ${compCount}, ReteCount: ${retentionCount}");
                if (compCount > retentionCount) {
                    log.info("CompDate: ${comp.lastUpdated()} RetDate: ${retentionDate}");
                    if(comp.lastUpdated().isBefore(retentionDate)) {
                        log.info("compDate after retentionDate: ${comp.lastUpdated()} isAfter ${retentionDate}");
                        log.info("deleting ${comp.group()}, ${comp.name()}, version: ${comp.version()}");

                        // ------------------------------------------------
                        // uncomment to delete components and their assets
                        // service.deleteComponent(repo, comp);
                        // ------------------------------------------------

                        log.info("component deleted");
                        deletedComponentCount++;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                compCount = 1;
                previousComp = comp.group() + comp.name();
            }
        }else{
            log.info("Component skipped: ${comp.group()} ${comp.name()}");
        }
    }

    log.info("Deleted Component count: ${deletedComponentCount}");
}
```

https://github.com/xninjaxelitex/nexus3-cleanup-release-artifact

This script will clean your nexus repository by the specified parameters at the top.

Comment: If i try to run it via a curl call at the api i get the following error:
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:\nScript12.groovy: 1: Ambiguous expression could be either a parameterless closure expression or an isolated open code block;\n   solution: Add an explicit closure parameter list, e.g. {it -> ...}, or force it to be treated as an open block by giving it a label, e.g. L:{...} @ line 1, column 1.\n   {\n   ^\n\n1 error\n"

Comment: Did you remove the marked code section at the top of the script? I have only tested it within Nexus directly never with curl.

Comment: +1 this solution works. Don't forget to modify the code and comment/uncomment lines as instructed in the script.

Comment: the delete api seems to be changed in our version.  I replaced the service.deleteComponent with:
`try{
                            tx = repo.facet(StorageFacet.class).txSupplier().get();
                            tx.begin();
                            tx.deleteComponent(comp);
                        }finally{
                            if(tx!=null){
                                tx.close();
                            }
                        }`

Comment: @ninjaxelite , is running this script enough to free up the disk space? or does it require some additional actions? I ran my script using the same mechanism (service.deleteComponent()) to remove a single package and the package seems to be gone from nexus, but I haven't noticed any freed disk space on my nexus

Comment: @rideronthestorm If the package is successfully deleted, it should of course free the disk space.

Comment: @rideronthestorm It does free the disk space but it does not do it automatically and takes some time after the delete() command is executed from the script. Besides, I have executed the "rebuild index" command in the repository and the compact blob store task for the corresponding blob store used by the repository.

Comment: @ninjaxelite I found that the ordering is not fully correct if using the script. A version 1.10 will appear before a version 1.2. Is there a way to sort those using the natural sort order? (Also taking into account e.g. RC-10, RC-1 versions)?

Answer (score 7):

See this script as a basis to work with:

https://gist.github.com/emexelem/bcf6b504d81ea9019ad4ab2369006e66 by emexelem

```
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.StorageFacet;
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.Query;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;

def fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
// Get a repository
def repo = repository.repositoryManager.get('nuget-releases');
// Get a database transaction
def tx = repo.facet(StorageFacet).txSupplier().get();
// Begin the transaction
tx.begin();
// Search assets that havn't been downloaded for more than three months
tx.findAssets(Query.builder().where('last_downloaded <').param(DateTime.now().minusMonths(3).toString(fmt)).build(), [repo]).each { asset ->
  def component = tx.findComponent(asset.componentId());
  // Check if there is newer components of the same name
  def count = tx.countComponents(Query.builder().where('name').eq(component.name()).and('version >').param(component.version()).build(), [repo]);
  if (count > 0) {
    log.info("Delete asset ${asset.name()} as it has not been downloaded since 3 months and has a newer version")
    tx.deleteAsset(asset);
    tx.deleteComponent(component);
  }
}
// End the transaction
tx.commit();
```

Answer (score 4):

So, I hit a problem with running out of diskspace as our releases/builds were stacking up, so I had a bit of a dig around at creating a script to remove old builds, and got to this:

```
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.StorageFacet;
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.Query;

def repositoryName = 'Integration';
def maxArtifactCount = 20;

// Get a repository
def repo = repository.repositoryManager.get(repositoryName);
// Get a database transaction
def tx = repo.facet(StorageFacet).txSupplier().get();
try {
    // Begin the transaction
    tx.begin();

    def previousComponent = null;
    def uniqueComponents = [];
    tx.findComponents(Query.builder().suffix(' ORDER BY group, name').build(), [repo]).each{component -> 
        if (previousComponent == null || (!component.group().equals(previousComponent.group()) || !component.name().equals(previousComponent.name()))) {
            uniqueComponents.add(component);
        }
        previousComponent = component;
    }

    uniqueComponents.each {uniqueComponent ->
        def componentVersions = tx.findComponents(Query.builder().where('group = ').param(uniqueComponent.group()).and('name = ').param(uniqueComponent.name()).suffix(' ORDER BY last_updated DESC').build(), [repo]);
        log.info(uniqueComponent.group() + ", " + uniqueComponent.name() + " size " + componentVersions.size());
        if (componentVersions.size() > maxArtifactCount) {
            componentVersions.eachWithIndex { component, index ->
                if (index > maxArtifactCount) {
                    log.info("Deleting Component ${component.group()} ${component.name()} ${component.version()}")
                    tx.deleteComponent(component);
                }
            }
        }
    }
} finally {
    // End the transaction
    tx.commit();
}
```

This works through a repository, looking for all the components.  It then works through all the versions (ordered by last updated - I couldn't figure out ordering by version number, but I think this should be ok), and then removes any over the maxArtifactCount number.

Hopefully this may be of use - and if you see any issues let me know.

Answer (score 3):

We do not have this scheduled task built yet, in the meantime you can use the Delete Component functionality in the UI if you need to manually remove a release.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to manually remove released components ? We have a lot of components and clicking on delete button on each of them one by one is tedious.

Comment: Not in a bulk manner via the UI, yet. There is a potential to write a groovy script that does this using the scripting API however.

Comment: Any news here? Have you scheduled it?

Comment: Not as of yet, sorry.

Comment: This purge feature is even more important as with usage of blob storage in nexus 3, we are not able to clean artifacts directly from the file system.
I had a look at https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/scripting.html and https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-book-examples/tree/nexus-3.x/scripting but did not find any obvious way to script the purge of a batch of releases. Would you have any more precise starting point to provide?

Comment: I'm raising this internally, and I agree with you Maxime. No starting point yet, but if you wanted to homebrew this you'd want to take a look at how the Snapshot Removal task works, and then engineer something that does effectively the same for Releases. I'll see if I can get something better for you in the future.

Comment: One of my colleague has written this script to clean old releases, i hope it will be useful for others:

Answer (score 3):

Old Thread but still a current topic.

After upgrading from Nexus 2.x to Nexus 3.x, the build-in function for keeping the latest X releases was sadly gone.
Ofcourse there is a feature-request for that: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-10821

I tried the Script by Matt Harrison (see earlier in this thread),
but the migration-tool in Nexus reseted all *last_updated*-values to the date of the migration, sad again.

I tried to sort the releases by *version* via ' ORDER BY version DESC', but that resulted in a mess, where a version *3.9.0* is newer than *3.11.0* and so on, not suitable in my scenario.

So I added some helper-lists, more logoutput (credits to neil201) and the version-sorter by founddrama (https://gist.github.com/founddrama/971284) to the script - And voila, I had a well working solution!

```html
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.StorageFacet;
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.Query;

def repositoryName = 'myrepo';
def maxArtifactCount = 42;

log.info("==================================================");
log.info(":::Cleanup script started...");
log.info("==================================================");
log.info(":::Operating on Repository: ${repositoryName}");
log.info("==================================================");

// Get a repository
def repo = repository.repositoryManager.get(repositoryName);
// Get a database transaction
def tx = repo.facet(StorageFacet).txSupplier().get();
try {
    // Begin the transaction
    tx.begin();

    int totalDelCompCount = 0;
    def previousComponent = null;
    def uniqueComponents = [];
    tx.findComponents(Query.builder().suffix(' ORDER BY group, name').build(), [repo]).each{component -> 
        if (previousComponent == null || (!component.group().equals(previousComponent.group()) || !component.name().equals(previousComponent.name()))) {
            uniqueComponents.add(component);
        }
        previousComponent = component;
    }

    uniqueComponents.each {uniqueComponent ->
        def componentVersions = tx.findComponents(Query.builder().where('group = ').param(uniqueComponent.group()).and('name = ').param(uniqueComponent.name()).suffix(' ORDER BY last_updated DESC').build(), [repo]);
        log.info("Processing Component: ${uniqueComponent.group()}, ${uniqueComponent.name()}");

        def foundVersions = [];
        componentVersions.eachWithIndex { component, index ->
          foundVersions.add(component.version());
         }
         log.info("Found Versions: ${foundVersions}")

        // version-sorting by founddrama 
        def versionComparator = { a, b ->
          def VALID_TOKENS = /.-_/
          a = a.tokenize(VALID_TOKENS)
          b = b.tokenize(VALID_TOKENS)
          
          for (i in 0..<Math.max(a.size(), b.size())) {
            if (i == a.size()) {
              return b[i].isInteger() ? -1 : 1
            } else if (i == b.size()) {
              return a[i].isInteger() ? 1 : -1
            }
            
            if (a[i].isInteger() && b[i].isInteger()) {
              int c = (a[i] as int) <=> (b[i] as int)
              if (c != 0) {
                return c
              }
            } else if (a[i].isInteger()) {
              return 1
            } else if (b[i].isInteger()) {
              return -1
            } else {
              int c = a[i] <=> b[i]
              if (c != 0) {
                return c
              }
            }
          }
          
          return 0
        }

        sortedVersions = foundVersions.sort(versionComparator)
        
        log.info("Sorted Versions: ${sortedVersions}")

        removeVersions = sortedVersions.dropRight(maxArtifactCount)
        
        totalDelCompCount = totalDelCompCount + removeVersions.size();
        
        log.info("Remove Versions: ${removeVersions}");
        
        log.info("Component Total Count: ${componentVersions.size()}");

        log.info("Component Remove Count: ${removeVersions.size()}");

        if (componentVersions.size() > maxArtifactCount) {
            componentVersions.eachWithIndex { component, index ->
                if (component.version() in removeVersions) {
                    log.info("Deleting Component: ${component.group()}, ${component.name()} ${component.version()}")
                    // ------------------------------------------------
                    // uncomment to delete components and their assets
                    // tx.deleteComponent(component);
                    // ------------------------------------------------
                }
            }
        }
        log.info("==================================================");
     
    }
    log.info(" *** Total Deleted Component Count: ${totalDelCompCount} *** ");
    log.info("==================================================");

} finally {
    // End the transaction
    tx.commit();
}
```

You can fork this script on github now: https://github.com/PhilSwiss/nexus-cleanup

Answer (score 1):

Although this post is quite old I had a similar requirement but wanted to remove old artifacts/releases based on the versions only, so needed to find a way to sort them and keep only the latest.

This is the script I came up with that is based on some of those examples already given here.

Note this was specifically for cleaning YUM repositories but should work for other types with little modification.

```
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.StorageFacet;
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.Query;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.slf4j.Logger

///////////////////////////////
def retentionCount = 3;
def repositoryName = 'repo-name';
def whitelist = [].toArray();
///////////////////////////////

log.info("==================================================");
log.info(":::Cleanup script started...");
log.info("==================================================");
log.info(":::Operating on Repository: ${repositoryName}");
log.info("==================================================");

def repo = repository.repositoryManager.get(repositoryName);
def tx = repo.facet(StorageFacet.class).txSupplier().get();
def components = null;

try {
    // Begin the transaction
    tx.begin();
    components = tx.browseComponents(tx.findBucket(repo));

    if(components != null) {
        int compCount = 0;
        int delCompCount = 0;
        int totalDelCompCount = 0;
        def listOfComponents = ImmutableList.copyOf(components);
        def previousComponent = null;
        def uniqueComponents = [];

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        final Long MAX_NUMBER = 10000L;

        listOfComponents.each { component ->
            if(!whitelist.contains(component.name())) {
                if (previousComponent == null || !component.name().equals(previousComponent.name())) {
                uniqueComponents.add(component);
            }
            previousComponent = component;
        }
    }

    uniqueComponents.each { uniqueComponent ->

        log.info("Starting Processing on Component: ${uniqueComponent.name()}");

        def artifactVersions = [];
        def numberArray = new ArrayList<Long>();

        tx.findComponents(Query.builder().where('name = ').param(uniqueComponent.name()).build(), [repo]).each { component ->
            def artifactVersion = component.version().replaceAll('-', '.');
            artifactVersions.add(artifactVersion);
        }

        log.info("Found Versions: ${artifactVersions}");

        for(ver in artifactVersions) {

            String[] vers = ver.split('\\.');

            Long num = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < vers.length; ++i) {
                num = num + Long.valueOf(vers[i]) * (long) Math.pow(MAX_NUMBER, vers.length - i - 1);
            }
            numberArray.add(num);
        }

        numberArray = numberArray.sort(); //.reverse();

        //log.info("Sorting the Versions: ${numberArray}");

        def sortedArtifactVersions = [];

        for (num in numberArray) {
            List<Long> parts = new ArrayList<>();

            while (num > 0) {
                parts.add((long) (num % MAX_NUMBER));
                num = Math.floorDiv(num, MAX_NUMBER);
            }
            String artifact = parts.reverse().join('.');
            sortedArtifactVersions.add(artifact);
        }

        log.info("Sorted Versions: ${sortedArtifactVersions}");

        compCount = sortedArtifactVersions.size();

        def toRemoveArtifactVersions = [];

        if (compCount > retentionCount) {
            toRemoveArtifactVersions = sortedArtifactVersions.dropRight(retentionCount);
        }

        delCompCount = toRemoveArtifactVersions.size();

        totalDelCompCount = totalDelCompCount + delCompCount;

        log.info("Remove Versions: ${toRemoveArtifactVersions}");

        log.info("Component Total Count: ${compCount}");

        log.info("Component Remove Count: ${delCompCount}");

        for (ver in toRemoveArtifactVersions) {

            StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(ver);
            b.replace(ver.lastIndexOf("."), ver.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, "-" );
            ver = b.toString();

            tx.findComponents(Query.builder().where('name = ').param(uniqueComponent.name()).and('version = ').param(ver).build(), [repo]).each { component ->

                log.info("Deleting Component: ${uniqueComponent.name()} ${ver}");

                // ------------------------------------------------
                // uncomment to delete components and their assets
                // tx.deleteComponent(component);
                // ------------------------------------------------
            }
        }
        log.info("==================================================");
    }
    log.info(" *** Total Deleted Component Count: ${totalDelCompCount} *** ");
    log.info("==================================================");
}

// End the transaction
tx.commit();

} catch(Exception e) {
    log.info("Error: "+e);
    tx.rollback();
} finally {
    tx.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also fall in this quite old post with the need to delete old artifacts in release repository in Nexus 3.

After a migration from Nexus 2 all LastUpdated fields was overwritten with import timestamp and not all other solutions consider that. As can be seen in artifact details from repository browse, the useful information is `last_modified` field contained in `Attributes -> content`.

Starting from the posted solutions by [@ninjaxelite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46156944/2186777), thanks to [@Phil Swiss](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63192273/2186777) and [@neil201](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57604767/2186777), I tried to found a way by considering Assets and not Components (attributes are included in Assets).
A requirement was to keep at least N released versions also if the retention period has been ended.
I deal with sorting of the extracted artifacts, where myApp-war-2.12.3.war is considered more recent than myApp-war-2.2.3.war due to literal sorting, solved using @founddrama solution as in other posts.

Consider that the following solution extracts all records and takes a lot of memory and time to sort and check all items in repository each time the script is scheduled, I do not ensure it works correctly with large repos (tested with 1.5TB in 10 mins). Any enhancement in performances it is well appreciated.

```
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.StorageFacet;
import org.sonatype.nexus.common.app.GlobalComponentLookupHelper
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.maintenance.MaintenanceService
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.ComponentMaintenance
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.Query;
import org.sonatype.nexus.script.plugin.RepositoryApi
import org.sonatype.nexus.script.plugin.internal.provisioning.RepositoryApiImpl
import com.google.common.collect.Lists
import com.google.common.collect.Iterables
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.slf4j.Logger

// ----------------------------------------------------
// delete these rows when this script is added to nexus
//RepositoryApiImpl repository = null;
//Logger log = null;
//GlobalComponentLookupHelper container = null;
// ----------------------------------------------------

// ---------------------- CONFIG ------------------------------
// ATTENTION: This script is skilled for maven repos

// 5 Years of RetentionDays
def retentionDays = 1825;
def retentionCount = 3;
def repositoryName = 'Repository-Name';
def whitelist = ["org.javaee7.sample/javaee7-simple-sample", "org.javaee7.next/javaee7-another-sample"].toArray();
// ------------------------------------------------------------


log.info(":::Cleanup script of ${repositoryName} STARTED!");
MaintenanceService service = container.lookup("org.sonatype.nexus.repository.maintenance.MaintenanceService");
def repo = repository.repositoryManager.get(repositoryName);
def tx = repo.facet(StorageFacet.class).txSupplier().get();
def assets = null;
try {
    tx.begin();
    
    //CAREFUL!!  This query extracts all Assets, do filter the search where possible 
    assets = tx.browseAssets(tx.findBucket(repo));
}catch(Exception e){
    log.info("Error: "+e);
}finally{
    if(tx!=null)
        tx.close();
}

if(assets != null) {
    def retentionDate = DateTime.now().minusDays(retentionDays).dayOfMonth().roundFloorCopy();
    int deletedAssetsCount = 0;
    int assetCount = 1;
    
    List<Iterables> listOfAssets = Lists.newArrayList(assets);
    
    //Base Path of each single project, it will be used for retention count (for each project it will not deleted versions at retentionCount amount)
    def assetBasePath = listOfAssets.head().attributes().get('maven2').get('groupId')+"."+listOfAssets.head().attributes().get('maven2').get('artifactId');
    def currentAsset = null;
    def assetFilename = null;
    
    // ----> ######## Asset List Sorting ##########
    // Considering version number in filename, i.e. myApp-war-2.12.3.war is more recent than myApp-war-2.2.3.war
    
    // version-sorting by founddrama 
    def versionComparator = { itemA, itemB ->
      def VALID_TOKENS = /.-_/
      
      def a = itemA.name().tokenize(VALID_TOKENS)
      def b = itemB.name().tokenize(VALID_TOKENS)
      
      for (i in 0..<Math.max(a.size(), b.size())) {
        if (i == a.size()) {
          return b[i].isInteger() ? -1 : 1
        } else if (i == b.size()) {
          return a[i].isInteger() ? 1 : -1
        }
        
        if (a[i].isInteger() && b[i].isInteger()) {
          int c = (a[i] as int) <=> (b[i] as int)
          if (c != 0) {
            return c
          }
        } else if (a[i].isInteger()) {
          return 1
        } else if (b[i].isInteger()) {
          return -1
        } else {
          int c = a[i] <=> b[i]
          if (c != 0) {
            return c
          }
        }
      }
      
      return 0
    }
    
    log.info("Extracted Asset List Sorting ...");
    listOfAssets = listOfAssets.sort(versionComparator);
    log.info("Extracted Asset List Sorted");
    
    // <---- ######## Asset List Sorting ##########

    listOfAssets.reverseEach{asset ->
    
        if (asset.attributes().get('maven2').get('asset_kind').equals("REPOSITORY_METADATA")){
            //The metadata files are skipped by default
            currentAsset = null;
        }else if (
                asset.attributes().get('maven2').get('groupId') != null
            &&  asset.attributes().get('maven2').get('artifactId') != null
        ){
            // By default the asset basePath it will considered as groupId + artifactId maven attributes
            currentAsset = asset.attributes().get('maven2').get('groupId')+"."+asset.attributes().get('maven2').get('artifactId');
            assetFilename = asset.attributes().get('maven2').get('version')+"."+asset.attributes().get('maven2').get('extension');
        }else{
            // Otherwise, for raw files (and i.e. maven-metadata.xml) the same basePath it is decoded from filename
            // Obvious, it can be used this way in each case avoiding previous code, but I consider it as the second chance
            
            // Cut from penultimate occurrence of / to the end, then replace / with .
            currentAsset = asset.name().replaceAll("(.*)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)", '$1').replaceAll("/", ".");
            assetFilename = asset.name().replaceAll("(.*)/([^/]+)", '$2');
        }
        
        if (currentAsset != null && !whitelist.contains(currentAsset)){
            log.info("Processing Asset : ${currentAsset}, filename: ${assetFilename}");
            log.info("AssetBasePath: ${assetBasePath}");
                
            if(assetBasePath.equals(currentAsset)) {
                log.info("AssetCount: ${assetCount}, Retention: ${retentionCount}");
                if (assetCount > retentionCount) {
                    def lastModifiedDate = asset.attributes().get('content').get('last_modified');
                    DateTime lastModifiedDateTime = lastModifiedDate==null?null:new DateTime(lastModifiedDate);
                    
                    log.debug("AssetLastModified: ${lastModifiedDateTime} - RetentionDate: ${retentionDate}");
                    
                    if (retentionDate.isAfter(lastModifiedDateTime)) {
                        log.info("AssetLastModified ${lastModifiedDateTime} isOldestThan than RetentionDate ${retentionDate}");
                        log.info("Deleting: ${currentAsset}, filename: ${assetFilename}");

                        // ------------------------------------------------
                        // uncomment to delete assets
                        // service.deleteAsset(repo, asset);
                        // ------------------------------------------------

                        log.info("Asset DELETED");
                        deletedAssetsCount++;
                    }
                }
                assetCount++;
            } else {
                assetCount = 1;
                assetBasePath = currentAsset;
            }
        }else{
            log.info("Asset skipped due to whitelisted or Format not supported: ${asset.name()}");
        }
    }

    log.info("TASK END - TOTAL Deleted Asset count: ${deletedAssetsCount}");
}
```

The solution is skilled for a Maven repository, but with some changes I hope it can be useful for all types of repo.
Remember to schedule also "Compact blob store" task in order to free disk space after artifact deletion.