# How to automatically delete old versions of artifacts from hosted maven repository on OSS 3.0.0?

Tags: maven, maven-2, nexus

We are building and deploying multiple releases for various services in a single day. Due to this we are wasting a lot of storage for storing older versions of artifacts which will never be used again.

Is there a way to automatically delete older versions and just keep few versions such as last 10 in [OSS 3.0.0](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-oss)?

I searched there documentation but couldn't find anything that works automatically. Currently I have to manually select and delete them which is very error prone and time consuming.

Few details about my setup:

1. "File" type "blob" is used for storage.
2. Repository is self "hosted" with format "maven2"

Comment: First why using an older version Nexus? What about using the REST API to handle this? See http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/scripting.html

Comment: Thanks for your pointers. At the time of setup, 3.0.0 was the latest version available from them. I will check their rest-api's.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options you can use in Nexus Repository 3.x for Snapshots, from https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/admin.html#admin-system-tasks:

- Purge unused Maven snapshot versions
- Remove snapshots from Maven repository

As for Releases, removing Releases can be an anti-pattern, you generally should keep your releases around if others rely on them, etc...

There is a JIRA ticket for Removing Releases which you can follow at: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-10821

This is also answered here: [Purge old release from Nexus 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40742766/purge-old-release-from-nexus-3)