# Nexus Repository Manager - removing old binary resources

Tags: java, nexus, artifacts, nexus3, resource-cleanup

I wonder if there is a way to delete many items from nexus repository. I have some `RAW` type repositories with some web application releases(simple tar.bz2
binary files):

[image]

In some repositories are a lot of them. I want to free up some disk space. I can delete individual files:

[image]

but I don't see a bulk removal option.

**The best solution for me would be to automatically or manually clean up old files. It's possible in free version? If yes - how?**

I don't see `Cleanup Policies` in main menu:

[image]

`Nexus Repository ManagerOSS 3.3.2-02`

Comment: Did you read about the [Cleanup Policies](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/cleanup-policies)?

Comment: Good advice. I've read this material, unfortunately `Admin - Cleanup Tags` are available only for professional versions. I use opensource version.

Comment: Do you need the `Admin - Cleanup Tags` task?

Comment: I need something to remove old unused releases from `raw` type repositories - automatically or manually :)

Comment: Arent unused tags =/= unused releases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution for my problem.

I don't have `Cleanup Policy` section in my admin console([I think this option is available only for professional or nevest versions](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/cleanup-policies)) - Thank you `@Sebastian` for your advices, you directed me to the solution.

Based on this question: [Purge old release from Nexus 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40742766/purge-old-release-from-nexus-3)

I created some manual tasks to cleanup my binary repositories:

[image]

My cleanup task is very simple but anyone who needs something more complicated can write own Groovy script or look for ready solutions.

```
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.Component
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.Query
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.StorageFacet

def removeFromDate = '2019-02-01'

log.info("delete components for repository: HereYourRepoName")
def compInfo = { Component c -> "${c.group()}:${c.name()}:${c.version()}[${c.lastUpdated()}]}" }
def repo = repository.repositoryManager.get("HereYourRepoName")
StorageFacet storageFacet = repo.facet(StorageFacet)

def tx = storageFacet.txSupplier().get()
tx.begin()
Iterable<Component> components = tx.findComponents(Query.builder().where('last_updated < ').param(removeFromDate).build(), [repo])
tx.commit()
tx.close()

log.info("about to delete " + components.flatten(compInfo))
for(Component c : components) {
    log.info("deleting " + compInfo(c))
    tx2 = storageFacet.txSupplier().get()
    tx2.begin()
    tx2.deleteComponent(c)
    tx2.commit()
    tx2.close()
}

log.info("finished deleting " + components.flatten(compInfo))
```

Logs viewer is very helpful to debug scripts :)

Comment: You need to upgrade, version 3.3.2 is quite old. Cleanup policies are not in that version.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is impossible for the moment but thanks for the advice :)

Comment: FTR, the Cleanup Policies are available since NXRM 3.14.0

Answer (score 23):

This is perfectly possible with Nexus3 OSS:

**1. Create a cleanup policy**
Under "Repository -> Cleanup Policies" you can add a policy that deletes artifacts from a repository that:

- Are published before X days
- Last downloaded before X days

**2. Add this policy to your repository**
Edit your repository. Under "Cleanup Policy" select your new policy.

Since cleaned up repositories only [soft-delete](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/cleanup-policies) the artifacts (mark them for deleteion) you need to:

**3. Compact your blob store**
Go to "System -> Tasks -> Create Task", select the "Admin - Compact Blob Store" task, select the blob store of your repository and configure this task to run after the cleanup task.

All this is described in more detail in the [nexus documentation](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/cleanup-policies).

I have tested the steps with Nexus 3.15.2-01 OSS edition.

Comment: Can you add some screenshots? I don't see `cleanup policy` section: https://photos.app.goo.gl/jSsaDWbven6sEmxg8

Comment: [Image](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/files/16355798/16355800/1/1539367151811/Screen+Shot+2018-08-02+at+4.12.57+PM.png). Do you have admin privilege?

Comment: I can remove and modify all repositories, blob stories and so on... so I think I have admin permissions - I don't see `Cleanup Policies` in my menu.

Comment: Yes I have admin permissions: https://photos.app.goo.gl/t2t3aNuXEkkcp5uFA

Comment: @KrzysztofRaciniewski The Cleanup Policies were added in NXRM 3.14.0 - what version are you running?

Comment: Nexus Repository ManagerOSS 3.3.2-02

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian I missed  "Add this policy to your repository" part.